# Is it possible to use memSQL/SingleStore with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, singlestore

I want to use SingleStore database with my Spring Boot Application which uses Spring Data JPA. How it can be achieved?

Comment: According to [single store](https://www.singlestore.com/forum/t/which-spring-boot-dependency-should-i-use-to-integrate-with-a-singlestore-database/2911/3), you only need (spring-boot-data-starter-jpa and) maria db driver in your classpath.. (+ connection string, "authentication",...)

Answer (score 0):

To leverage SingleStoreDB with Spring Boot, you would use the JDBC connectors for both technologies - [Spring](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc) + [SingleStore](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.6/en/developer-resources/connect-with-application-development-tools/connect-with-java-jdbc/the-singlestore-jdbc-driver.html). If you are using some ORM style features, use the mysql dialect. If you run into issues you can raise them here, on the [forum](https://www.singlestore.com/forum/) or to support if you're an active customer.